# Kendo contextMenu select function for specific items

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-contextmenu

I'm trying to create a contextMenu usig the kendoContextMenu widget. This works using the following code.

```
$("#contextMenu").kendoContextMenu({
target: "#tree",
filter: ".k-item",
select: function(e) {
    alert("Selected");
},
dataSource:
[
    { text: "Item1"},
    {
        text: "SubMenu1",
        items: [
            { text: "Item1" }
        ]
    },
    {
        text: "SubMenu2",
        items: [
            { text: "Item1" }
        ]
    }
]
});
```

But I want to specify a function for each item to execute when the item is clicked. I don't want to determine what to execute based on the text contents.

I've tried to add a click item in the datasource but that doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kendo ContextMenu doesn't have this feature, but you have 2 options:

First, configure context menu using html with `onclick` events:

```
<ul id="menu">
    <li>
        Option 1
        <ul>
            <li onclick="alert('test');">Sub option 1</li>
            <li>Sub option 2</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Option 2</li>
</ul>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {        
        $("#menu").kendoContextMenu({
                orientation: orientation,
            });
        };
    });
</script>
```

Second, if you can ensure name uniqueness you can add click properties in `dataSource` configuration and then on context menu select event you can search in `dataSource` appropriate item and execute attached function manually.

Comment: I Can't ensure name uniqueness so option 2 is not possible. That is also one of the reasons that the content of the item is not enough information to determine what to do in the "global" select function.

The problem with your first solution is that I don't have the event info e.target available when I add onclick handlers on the li elements.

Comment: At this point I've used your first solution, in combination with storing the target in the open event of the menu.

Answer (score 1):

Other way its to add select function and switch case, this is case when you have treeview:

```
$("#menu").kendoContextMenu({
            select: function (e) {
                var button = $(e.item);
                var node = $(e.target);
                var tmpKendDiagram = $(".diagram").data("kendoDiagram");

                var tv = $(".tree-view").data("kendoTreeView");
                var item = tv.dataItem(node);
                var textSelect = $(e.item).children(".k-link").text();
                switch (textSelect) {
                    case '1option':
                        //do stuff
                        break;
                    case '2option':
                        //do stuf
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but this is the way I have implemented it

```js
$("#context-menu").kendoContextMenu({
  target: "#target",
  select: function(e) {
    let index = $(e.item).index();
    e.sender.options.dataSource[index].click(e);
  },
  dataSource: [
    {text: "Copy",
      click: function(e) {
        console.log("copied");
      }
    },
    {text: "Delete",
      click: function(e) {
        console.log("deleted");
      }
    }
  ]
});
```

```html
<link href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2020.1.406/styles/kendo.common.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2020.1.406/styles/kendo.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2020.1.406/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>

<div id="target">Target</div>
<div id="context-menu"></div>
```